# why subtraction return - symbol

Tags: bash, shell

I have a problem with a simple subtraction but I don't understand what's wrong.

My code :

```
start= date +%s%N | cut -b1-13
#Treatment...
end= date +%s%N | cut -b1-13

delta=`expr $end - $start`
echo "delta $delta"
```

My console display :

```
  1374652348283
  ...
  1374652349207
  delta -
```

My question is :  Why do I got a - symbol returned ?

Comment: That fact that your start and end times are displayed without you printing them should have alerted you to the fact that something didn't go right with the assignments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command:

```
a= b
```

(note the space) will set `a` to an empty string while it runs the command `b`. It's a way to temporarily set environment variables for a single command, things like:

```
PATH=/path/to/somwhere gcc whatever  # Here, PATH has the modified value.
echo $PATH                           # Here, PATH has its original value.
```

So the command line:

```
start= date +%s%N | cut -b1-13
```

sets `start` temporarily to nothing and runs the `date` command. Hence both `start` and `end` are still empty when you use them, which is why you only get the `-`, since `expr -` just gives you `-`.

If you want to get the results of the `date` command into a variable, use:

```
start=$(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13)
```

Answer (score 5):

You didn't assign to the variables. **You must not have spaces around the equals sign.**

Also, you're doing it wrong.

```
start=$(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13)
```